# Problems with form with dynamic number fields

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have this form with some dynamic fields called num_entradas.

If you add some numeric values onchange calculates the sum of all the fields with the function sumarTotalEntradas():

All of these works fine, but the problem is when I submit the form to a PHP page I only get the last field value. If I change the name attribute of the fields to num_entradas[] the submit is ok but then the sumaTotalEntradas() function doesn't work and totalEntradas fields remains in 0.

```js
function sumarTotalEntradas() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('num_entradas');
  var tot = 0;
  var subtotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot = tot + subtotal;
  }
  document.getElementById('totalEntradas').value = tot;

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" min="0" step="1" maxlength="2" name="num_entradas" id="num_entradas" value="0" onchange="sumarTotalEntradas()">
  <input type="number" min="0" step="1" maxlength="2" name="num_entradas" id="num_entradas" value="0" onchange="sumarTotalEntradas()">
  <input type="number" min="0" step="1" maxlength="2" name="num_entradas" id="num_entradas" value="0" onchange="sumarTotalEntradas()">
  Total: <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="totalEntradas" id="totalEntradas" value="0"> €
</form>
```

Comment: Ids should be unique. It's not valid to have more than 1 element with the same id on your page.

Comment: The field names should be sent to php as an array i.e. name="num_entradas[]".

Comment: @Natrium  he is not using the IDs at all. It is not the problem here. It is still not valid though

Comment: Jeff, as I said if I change the name attribute to num_entradas[] the javascript function doesnt work.

Comment: ALso your code is wrong,.  I removed the trailing 2 from sumar... and you need to do `var val = arr[i].value; if (!isNaN(val) && val !=="") tot += parseInt(val);`

Comment: You can get the number fields using `document.querySelectorAll("[name^=num_entradas]")` if you do not want to bother with the []